# Django password change view form

Tags: django, change-password

I'm still new to Django and have a few questions on how using built in views work. I noticed that djang comes with a built in password change view at django.contrib.auth.views.password_change. This view shows the admin site in the background of the template, while I want to provide my own css/template but keep the form and functionality of that view. How would I do this? Can you pass something into the urls.py

```
r'password_change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change')
```

like a custom template? I am unsure of the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the template that should be used by setting the `template_name` argument:

```
(r'password_change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'template_name': 'path/to/password_reset.html'})
```

In your template make sure you use the provided `{{ form }}` template variable and you're good to go.

Answer (score 6):

Django will attempt to load templates first from your application, then fall back. So, to override the templates for contrib.auth, you just need to:

1. Create a directory named `auth` in your template directory.
2. Create a template of the same name that the built-in view is expecting to load.
3. There is no step 3.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around then? First on the project template directory and then fall back to the app?

Comment: By "your application" I mean the Django project. The template directory I referenced in "Step 1" is the primary template directory in the *project*. If you add a directory synonymous to one already present in Django, your template directory will override the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can provide an url to the successful change with:

```
url(r'^password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {'post_change_redirect' : '/password-changed/','template_name': 'password.html'},),
```

Comment: castilo, are you addressing accepted answer or the question? Try make your answer a bit more clearer regarding this